# Want to Update the Route Param value from the api even if the user changes the value manually

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I am adding two id's in the route as a param using Resolve. So the id's will get add into the route before it navigates. So, If the user changes those id's in the url manually and reload the page, I want to get the old id which was added using resolve.Here are 123 and 456 are the two real id's.

```
http://localhost:4200/hello/123/456/
```

Now if the user enters manually 890 and 897 and they are reloading the page.Now I want to add the real id while page is reloading.

```
http://localhost:4200/hello/890/897

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    const opportunity = route.paramMap.get('opportunity');
    const quote = route.paramMap.get('quote');
    // alert(opportunity);
    if (opportunity === null || quote === null) {
      // alert(opportunity);
      return this.cartService.createOpportunityId().pipe(
        withLatestFrom( // multiple sevices as object to resolve.
          this.cartService.createQuoteId(),
        )
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: save them in localStorage or in a cookie and check them

Comment: can you add the code of your resolver please ?

Comment: I have added the resolve. Also I found the property in routes called runGuardsAndResolvers  which helps to find the changes in params and queryparams. But help me in implementation. I have added the property in routing module along with path, component.